# Manter o Adnroid conectado ao ESP8266 como access point

Tags: android, socket, iot

Em primeiro lugar todo o código funciona perfeitamente em qualquer celular que use uma versão do android anterior ao Lollipop. 
Dele para o mais recente é que o problema ocorre.
O que acontece é que o meu app conecta normalmente no AP criado no ESP8266, e até fica conectado. Mas o android marca como não tendo acesso à internet e desvia sozinho todas as chamadas do meu app para o acesso via 3G/4G.
Ou seja, fica conectado mas sem usar. E em alguns momentos ele desconecta sozinho e volta a se ligar no meu wifi.
Tentei todas as configurações disponíveis no android mas sem sucesso.
Existe alguma maneira de forçar a ele acessar meu ESP8266 pelo menos para as chamadas pelo socket?
Fazer root no telefone está fora de questão.

Comment: Um contorno é desligar os dados móveis. Os testes feitos com os dados moveis desligados funcionaram 100%.
Mas o problema é desligar ele manualmente ao entrar no app e religar ao sair.

Comment: Consegui usando essa solução: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329775/using-a-wifi-without-internet-connection/46165010#46165010